# RHEL environments in YugaByte DB

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Does Yugabyte work with RHEL environments? I didn’t see RHEL mentioned in the linux environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, YugaByte DB works with RHEL, and has been tested with RHEL 7.x OS.

This is mentioned here (link may be hard to get to): https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/checklist/#basics